# Stop event bubbling up using XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a `Grid` with a `Button` inside. The button has `Flyout` menu attached.

I implemented an action which opens the flyout menu when the button is tapped/clicked. This is the default behavior which does not require event writing. I also implemented an action when the grid is tapped/clicked.

The problem is that I do not want the grid to react when I tap/click the button. Based on [this fine read](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/03/understand-event-bubbling-and-tunneling-in-wpf-and-c/), it all makes sense, but in my case, I do not have any code behind to add the `e.Handled = true;` line to.

Is there any way I could stop event bubbling up the tree using `XAML` only? Thanks!

Comment: Put `ClickMode="Press"` on the `Button` since it's default is "Release" so the Grid doesn't get the event also, I don't think there's a need for any attached behaviors etc here. ;)

Comment: This is a better solution than suggested by Gusdor below. @ChrisW. please copy your comment as an answer so that I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough, one sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I hate to poach Gusdor's points. There is a built an enumeration property to deal with this types of situations called [ClickMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.clickmode(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can override the default mode for `Button` of `Release` and set it at the instance as `ClickMode="Press"` to get the desired effect and allow it to receive HitTestVisibility individually before any parent does.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to write some code but not the code behind you are trying to avoid.

1. Create an attached behavior that subscribes to, and handles the
   bubbling event.
2. Attach the behaviour to the element where you want
   the event bubbling to stop.

There is a Microsoft article about plugging Behaviours into UWP apps https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/